# Flutter - File google-services.json is missing. The Google Services Plugin cannot function without it

Tags: flutter, firebase

I am trying to run the flutter application on the android studio before now all works perfectly but after I changed my targetSdkVersion to `targetSdkVersion 31` I started getting this error that says

```
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve com.google.firebase:firebase-core:25.12.0.
     Required by:
         project :app
      > No cached version of com.google.firebase:firebase-core:25.12.0 available for offline mode.
```

And `google-services.json` is available in my project. My `pubspec.yaml` for firebase_message is `firebase_messaging: ^7.0.3`, `android/build.gradle`dependencies is

````
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.61'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()  // Maven Central repository
    }

dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
}


``` and my ```app/build.gradle``` dependencies is
````

```
dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.0.4'
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:31.0.2')

}
```

Thanks, in advance, please let me know if there is any information is needed

I tried to clean the project, pub upgrade, pub get, flutter upgrade, and even tried downloading a new version of firebase_messaging and pasting it inside the project still the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I was able to solve this by first updating my `firebase_messaging` version in `pubspec.yaml` to `firebase_messaging: ^13.0.4` And `android/build.gradle` dependencies is

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.5.31'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()  // Maven Central repository
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.3'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.13'

    }

    subprojects {
        project.configurations.all {
            resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { details ->
                if (details.requested.group == 'com.android.support'
                        && !details.requested.name.contains('multidex') ) {
                    details.useVersion "27.1.1"
                }

                if (details.requested.group == 'androidx.core'
                        && !details.requested.name.contains('androidx') ) {
                    //details.useVersion "1.0.1"
               details.useVersion "1.5.0"
                }
            }
        }
    }

}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()  // Maven Central repository
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

And and my `app/build.gradle` dependencies is

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 33

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "appname"
        minSdkVersion 20
        //noinspection OldTargetApi
        multiDexEnabled true
        targetSdkVersion 33
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}



dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:31.0.2')

}
```

The above solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

add build.repositories `jcenter()` and to allprojects.repositories `jcenter()`, in your build.gardle file

Comment: I have that added and still the same error

Comment: did you use firebase cli for connecting your app to firebase

Comment: Yes I connected and everything works well before I changed my targetSDK

Comment: try changing  targetsdkversion to 30

Comment: This didn't work